# Wrong encoding when getting response from Google's translate API?

Tags: asp.net

I am using google translate API to translate text from English to German.
The code i am using is:

```
string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", TxtEnglish.Text, Constants.LanguagePair);

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(TextTranslation_DownloadStringCompleted);
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
```

On receiving the response in `e.Result`.......
Original text: Can you help me?

Translated german text on translator page: `können Sie mir helfen`

Result in `e.Result`:  `k�nnen Sie mir helfen`

So, plz help me know why this "�" special character is coming and how can i fix this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler to check the response headers and you will find the encoding in there.

The way it is being shown could be unrelated to the data you receive and could be related to the way you are representing it in your UI code. Share that and we will have a look.